# how to convert time_t to something like "Fri, 12 Nov 2010 16:02:54 GMT " in C on Linux

Tags: c, gmt

I'm writing a simple web server in C on Linux.

I have to add the last modified time of a file that will be transferred to the client(browser),

I analysed how some websites and find out that they all present the time in format:

`Fri, 12 Nov 2010 16:02:54 GMT`,

my question is, can I transfer a time_t value to something string in the former format simply? Is there a function to do this? Or is the format unimportant at all?

Comment: cf. man ctime - hope this helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

strftime() is the function you need.

The wikipedia article on time_t gives a good example
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_t

Answer (score 2):

That looks like the format defined in [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt), you can convert a `time_t` to a `struct tm`, and format it to a using [strftime](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html) string like

```
struct tm time_tm;
char http_time[64];
time_t  t = time(NULL);
gmtime_r(&t,&time_tm);
strftime(http_time,sizeof http_time,"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000",&time_tm);
```

NOTE; strftime converts the names using the current locale, you might need to change the current locale to get the English names.

The HTTP spec also allow the format given by [asctime](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/asctime.html)()